# In ADF V2 - how to append date ("yyyyMMdd")) to filename dynamically for S3 dataset

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I'm currently working to automate a pipeline in ADFv2 where the source data sits in S3. A new file is created daily and is structured "data_20180829.csv"

I have tried to instrument dynamic content to accomplish this in the fileName field of Copy Data Activity. However even when I try something as simple as @{concat('data_','20180829.csv')} (that should resolve to the correct value) the source fails.

Is there any way to see what the dynamic content will resolve to?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the error message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should just be a matter of setting the filename expression in the dataset, eg

[image: Azure Data Factory dataset settings]

Note, the setting is done on the dataset not at the Copy activity level.  Also note you can make your expression more dynamic by combining the `utcnow` function with formatDateTime, eg something like this:

```
@concat('data_',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyMMdd_HHmmss'),'.csv')
```

Note carefully the case of the formatting strings.  Capital `MM` is for month in a two-digit format.  `HH` is for the hour in 24-hour format.  The full list of formatting strings is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

The json for the dataset looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "DelimitedText3",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "linkedService2",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "DelimitedText",
        "typeProperties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobStorageLocation",
                "fileName": {
                    "value": "@concat('data_',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyMMdd_HHmmss'),'.csv')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "container": "ang"
            },
            "columnDelimiter": ",",
            "escapeChar": "\\",
            "quoteChar": "\""
        },
        "schema": [
            {
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "type": "String"
            },
            {
                "type": "String"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
I was close, but was try to set the dynamic portion in the Copy activity.

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend what wBob called out . If you want the structure like foo_YYYY\MM\DD\ , you can always use this

```
@concat('foo-name','/',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy'),'/',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'MM'),'/',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'dd'))
```

Comment: I think you can do it one call eg `@concat('foo-name','/',formatDateTime(utcnow(),'yyyy/MM/dd'))`.  Feel free to upvote!  : )